# Why date command does not recognize my variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that takes a timestamp (just hours, no minutes) written in a file and transforms it in seconds since Epoch, but it is failing and I don't understand why.

The script that I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(cat time.txt)
stime=$(date --date "$(echo '$time')" +%s)
echo "$stime"
```

Contents of time.txt

```
06
```

Output:

```
date: invalid date ‘$time’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are single quoting the variable, so it is not being expanded to its contents. Try with double quotes, which allow expansion:

```
stime=$(date --date "$(echo "$time")" +%s)
```

BTW, I cannot see any reason to spawn a subshell to `echo` the variable when you can plainly give the variable to the command:

```
stime=$(date --date "$time" +%s)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the command

```
stime=$(date --date "$(echo '$time')" +%s)
```

You don't need the single quotes on $time. Just use it without them

```
stime=$(date --date "$(echo $time)" +%s)
```